# Sitecore Commerce 10.1 - Sitecore.Commerce.Engine in Customer.Sample.Solution does not run

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, sample

I have installed Sitecore 10.1 & Sitecore Commerce 10.1 in my local machine and trying to run the example `Customer.Sample.Solution`.

The solution builds without any errors.

The following changes are made in `Global.json`.

```
type - Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL.EntityStoreSqlPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL

Changed the username, password and server.
```

The following changes are made in `Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json`.

```
type - Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL.EntityStoreSqlPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL

Changed the username, password and server.
```

I selected the debugging profile as Engine in VS. The startup project is `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine`.

When I run the project after these changes, the error is:

> Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000

[image]

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the index manually by Sitecore control panel?

Comment: Also check PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json as well, does it have correct credentials.

Comment: This issue was resolved by stopping the CommerceAuthoring website in IIS and then running the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, before start running the debugging in VS, you have to make sure that you have stopped your Website and related AppPool in IIS.

Another option for debugging is "Attach to process".
In case of CE, the difference is that you have to attach to the executable `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.exe` process and not to the regular w3wp process.